# Snowflake Task Issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have created a snowflake task. The code is given below

```
create or replace task ANALYTICSLAYER.AN_CRMTS_P.TASK_CREATE_TABLE_U1

    warehouse=W_CRMTS_DEVELOPER
    
    schedule='USING CRON 0 10  * UTC'
    
    TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
    
    as CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ANALYTICSLAYER.AN_CRMTS_P.SMART_Report_All_Quote_Header_U1 AS SELECT * FROM  "ACCESSLAYER"."AC_CRMCLOUD_002_PRICING_P"."SMART Report - All Quote Header";
```

The task is running successfully but the table SMART_Report_All_Quote_Header_U1 is created with 0 records.

The role we use only allows read-only access to "ACCESSLAYER".AC_CRMCLOUD_002_PRICING_P"."SMART Report - All Quote Header".

If we create the table manually at the same time it gets created with non zero records .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ANALYTICSLAYER.AN_CRMTS_P.SMART_Report_All_Quote_Header_U2 AS SELECT * FROM  "ACCESSLAYER"."AC_CRMCLOUD_002_PRICING_P"."SMART Report - All Quote Header"
```

Could this be an issue with privileges?

Comment: When you run the CREATE manually are you using the same role that owns the task?